# How to transfer a Subversion repository from localhost to Github?

Tags: svn, git-svn

I have a working svn of my own project in my local machine. I have created a account in Github. Now I want to transfer this svn to Github with all commit logs and history.

Answer (score 1):

http://github.com/blog/156-subversion-importing

Answer (score 0):

Github has an option when creating a new repository, to import from an existing (public) Subversion repository. However, this only works if Github itself can reach your Subversion repository. Since your Subversion repository exists only on your local machine, you may find it easier to convert the repository to Git format first, *then* upload it to Github (which you can do with a simple `git push`).